# Qt embedding MYSQL

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qtsql

This Question has been asked by different people about 3times by [QLands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425104/qlands): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364157/use-mysql-embedded-with-qt/34727524) and [carnifrex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2459321/carnifrex): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092724/c-qt-embedded-mysql-server?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990142/qt-c-embedded-mysql?rq=1). My problem is exactly like [carnifrex's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990142/qt-c-embedded-mysql?rq=1): I am trying to compile my application to connect to MYSQL(Mariadb) database without Mariadb installation i.e embedded server but I get this Error Below:

`error: undefined reference to 'imp__ZN12QMYSQLDriverC1EP8st_mysqlP7QObject' collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Unfortunately, [carnifrex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2459321/carnifrex) was not replied. Here's my Code

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QSql>
#include <QMessageBox>

#include "qsql_mysql.h"
#include <mysql.h>

bool createConnection(QMYSQLDriver *drver)
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(drver);
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("exama");
    db.setPort(3306);
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("Adm1n16");

    if (!db.open()) {
        QMessageBox::warning(0, QObject::tr("Database Error"),
                             db.lastError().text());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MYSQL *mysql;

    static char *server_options[] = \
    {"mysql_test", "--defaults-file = C:/Program Files (x86)/MariaDB 10.1/data/my.cnf", NULL };
    int num_elements = (sizeof(server_options) / sizeof(char *)) - 1;

    static char *server_groups[] = { "embedded", NULL };

    qDebug() << "Loading embedded";
    mysql_library_init(num_elements, server_options, server_groups);
    mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "embedded");
    mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_OPT_USE_EMBEDDED_CONNECTION, NULL);

    mysql_real_connect(mysql, NULL,NULL,NULL, "database1", 0,NULL,0);

    QMYSQLDriver *drv = new QMYSQLDriver(mysql);

    if (!createConnection(drv))
        return 1;
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();

}
```

mysqlConnect.pro:

```
QT+=core gui sql\
        widgets \

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5): QT += widgets

INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Qt\Qt5.4\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtSql\5.4.0\QtSql\private"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB 10.1\include\mysql"

QMAKE_LIBDIR += "C:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB 10.1\lib"

LIBS += -lmysql

TARGET = mySQLConnect
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-std=c++11
```

The compilation fails at this line in main.cpp:

```
QMYSQLDriver *drv = new QMYSQLDriver(mysql);
```

I am using Qt Creator 5.4.0 with MingW 4.9.1 32bit on x64 bit Windows 7 Machine. I will be grateful for any assistance granted.

Comment: Are you sure your mysql was also compiled with MinGW? Mixing C++ compilers on Windows rarely works.

Comment: Am not sure...mariadb comes with x86 and x64 installers for windows so I used the dll files distributed with the x86 bit installer... X64 dll files could not work... Is there a way I can  away  I can  create my own libmysql.dll file with mingW?

Comment: I would first try use compile your work with the same compiler that mysql was compiled with, this takes much less time and will give you an answer what the real cause is.

Comment: I can't tell which compiler was used...all I know is that someone has succeeded compiling libmysql.dll with Qt creator.... I don't know but [Qland](http://stackoverflow.com/users/425104/qlands) seem to have compiled successfully only that the connection breaks down. Which compiler could be have been used? I will be happy for any assistance!

Comment: I have patiently waited for any substantial contribution about embedding mysql into Qt app with no avail. But I am still interested in this thread...is there no help out there?